# Append Delimiter to Rows using Octave's dlmwrite function

Tags: csv, octave

A toy example of problem: repeatedly using Octave's "dlmwrite" function thus

```
dlmwrite('file',[1 2],'-append',0,8);
```

will give

```
,,,,,,,,1,2
,,,,,,,,1,2
,,,,,,,,1,2
```

but what I really want is this

```
1,2,,,,,,,,,
1,2,,,,,,,,,
1,2,,,,,,,,,
```

How can I use the "dlmwrite" function to append the delimiter to rows, rather than prepend, to give the result I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `newline` option of `dlmwrite` to add commas before newline.

```matlab
comma = repmat(',', 1, 8); % creates ",,,,,,,,"
dlmwrite('file', [1 2], '-append', 'newline', [comma '\n']);
```

You can change `\n` to `\r\n` or `\r` if you are on Windows or Mac.